# What story had alien Invaders planting UFO stories to get us off guard?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember an old (pre-1980) short story about a reporter or investigator looking into stories about UFOs and possible alien landings.  They almost all seem like hoaxes or mistakes, except one happening that is witnessed by a reliable but blind man.  The blind man can attest that something weird happened, but it's not clear just what.

At the end, it is explained, but without any real details, that all the events were alien incursions.  However, they were deliberately unbelievable, to throw us off when the real invasion arrived.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [The Silly Season](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40941) by Cyril Kornbluth.

Various odd happenings are reported until the public gets sick of them: Shining Domes and Black Spheres appearing, circular pits in the ground, green capsules, etc.

It ends

> The people of the world were the sheep.
>
> We newsmen - radio, TV, press and wire services - were the boy, who
> should have been ready to sound the alarm.
>
> But the cunning wolves had tricked us into sounding the alarm so many
> times that the villagers were weary, and would not come when there was
> real peril.
>
> The wolves who were then burning their way through the Ozarks, utterly
> without opposition - the wolves were the Martians, under whose yoke
> and lash we now endure our miserable existences.

Comment: Dang!  Another Kornbluth story I didn't remember.